# htaccess redirect - subdomain with query ignored - subdomain only redirect to php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to allow sudomains containing queries or requests to be ignored:

e.g.
http://sub.domain.com/documents or http://sub.domain.com/index.php?user=fred

but if a URI is to a subdomain only

e.g.
http://sub.domain.com

if gets redirected to

http://sub.domain.com/portal.php

How do I do this using htaccess file ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_URI} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]

Answer (score 1):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /portal.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks man got this to work   -                                
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain.com$ [NC]

Comment: If you want this rule for `sub.domain` then using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain.com$ [NC]` won't always work when you have more than one sub domains. Better to be precise using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]`